Hardware supporting sign language to text input
I would like to know what hardware (and, what software), is available, to support sign language to text input.
Any support, pointers, or suggested implementations are welcome.

Search for Machine translation of sign language. Currently (nov 2025) there is a wikipedia page that seems promising.

I found this link, which seems very promising. Wikipedia has a number of pages on different sign languages, but I couldn't find a search result on Wikipedia corresponding to the book I found. Please, provide

Does the book cover input methods, besides, transition?
